# Strange if statement syntax with no body in a for loop

Tags: c++

I am working on a thirdparty API that has the following code somewhere in it:

```
// Toggle LEDs 4 time to show we are online
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    camManager.setCameraGpioOutput(cameraRight, IO_GPIO_1, 1);
    QThread::msleep(250);
    camManager.setCameraGpioOutput(cameraRight, IO_GPIO_1, 0);
    if(QThread::msleep(250); i < 4);
}
```

is that IF condition valid? I assume they wanted to omit the delay on the last loop but what sorcery is this?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if "If statement with initializer" since C++17. Though the code you have there does look like a bug.

Comment: @Mat Even with C++17, `QThread::msleep(250);` doesn't look like a valid declaration.

Comment: I think it's an _"expression statement"_

Comment: That code uses a new C++17 feature that allows an "init expression", but otherwise doesn't make any sense. You could just replace that statement with a plain `QThread::msleep(250);`.

Comment: Wait, C++17 `if` can have an arbitrary statement in it, not only a declaration? Huh.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat From the cppreference site, it seems it could be a declaration *or* any valid expression statement.

Comment: Just *guessing* here, but maybe the author misunderstood how the "init expression" works, and though that it would be executed conditionally depending on the actual condition. It doesn't work that way. What I think was intended is `if (i < 4) QThread::msleep(250);` Which *still* doesn't make sense since the condition will always be true inside the loop.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat + some programmer dude:  …. which means, unless I am mistaken, `class blah { int blah_blah; } i;` might be valid inside an `if()`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude they probably wanted it as `if (i < 3) QThread::msleep(250);`, in order to avoid the "trailing delay" as suggested by OP.

Comment: @tevemadar Yeah I guess so. So a misunderstanding *and* a typo.

Comment: @DEKKER: unless it is a very useful and unique library otherwise, you may want to consider checking for alternatives. Where this kind of ultra-modernized bug occurrs, there can be various others.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Yes that's a valid simple declaration.

Comment: I think a `perl` programmer has been in your code: `QThread::msleep(250) if(i < 4);` is perfectly logical in `perl`-land.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [if statement doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if):

```
    if constexpr /*optional*/ ( init-statement /*optional*/ condition ) statement-true
```

Are from C++17.

So indeed,

```
if(QThread::msleep(250); i < 4);
```

is valid, but mostly pointless as no action is taken. so it is equivalent to

```
QThread::msleep(250);
```

I think that code should simply be, to avoid last sleep:

```
if (i < 3) QThread::msleep(250);
```